# Свои логи на Google play

Tags: android, google-play

Опубликовал приложение в Play как альфа версию. На эмуляторе все работало, а через Play вылетает. В логах ошибка на null-объект. Этот объект не присваивается ранее по коду, а где не понятно (в эмуляторе и не реальном устройстве при непосредственной загрузки такого не было). Как можно задать свои логи по коду и потом их просмотреть на Play? Или может задача решается как-то другому.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать сервис [Crashlytics от Fabric'a](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install) например.